# Can you suppress certain events globally for all given elements of type input?

Tags: angular

I am beginning work on what will be a large angular 2 application.  In this application I would like to provide some global hot keys.  I plan on using a global event like:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
keyboardInput(event: KeyboardEvent)
```

However, it occured to me, that if a user typing something on an  element, then they can type a hotkey combination, then these global hotkey events will trigger.

This site will have countless input elements.  What I would like to know, if its even possible, that if any input element anywhere has focus, then disable the global hotkey capture logic.  I do not want to tie an event to every single hotkey like (focus)="service.disablehotkeys()" and the associated blur events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically ask for a way to remove/disable `@HostListener` and that is not possible (as from what I found). So best way, as I know, instead of HostListener create an Observable:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'window:keydown')
```

And subscribe / unsubscribe it when needed.

(I believe `@HostListener` under the hood does something similar)

Comment: That isn't quite what I meant.  For example, lets say I have 1000 input boxes here and there.  I do not want to write, 1000 times to subscribe / unsubscribe or enable / disable.   I want to be able to automatically, in some manner, disable / unsubscribe whenever any input box has focus.

Comment: @TheSilverHammer - you could add two `@HostListener`'s - one for `input:focus` other `input:blur` and unsubscribe / subscribe there